# performance advantages of compressing a drive holding Mysql data in windows 2008

Tags: mysql, windows, compression, drive

I was wondering if compressing a windows drive holding MyISAM tables will produce any performance enhancements for MySQL queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can produce better performance for SELECT queries (as it will read fewer bytes) but generally will slow down writes. Actually you can achieve the same with the `ARCHIVE` storage engine, which also compresses the data

Answer (score 0):

Negative. Lemple Ziv compression of large files, assumes if you are to read a large file, it shall not be random-access based. But that is what exactly MySQL does - finds a pointer to the data through (cached) keys and reads the row from large data file.

As pointed out by @Darhazer, it is better to use MySQL archiving features.